# AWS CDK add CreationPolicy to EC2 Instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Question in the title, trying to figure out how to add a CreationPolicy to an ec2 instance in the cdk so that I can then send a cfn-signal command once the script finishes, to then mark the resource as create complete.

This is what I have so far, after creating the ec2 instance in the stack:

```py
create_policy = CfnCreationPolicy(resource_signal=CfnResourceSignal(count=1, timeout="PT10M"))
```

I don't see a way in the docs to add that to the ec2 resource as a property. Just wondering what I should do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Creation Policy by setting a `CfnInstance` construct's [cfn_options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.CfnInstance.html#cfnoptions) attribute.

If your EC2 instance is built with the L2 `Instance` construct, first use [escape hatch syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_resource) to reference its underlying L1 `CfnInstance` construct:

```py
my_cfn_instance = my_instance.node.default_child

my_cfn_instance.cfn_options.creation_policy = create_policy
```